# Android 5.0 material tabs with toolbar

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

How can I achieve play store like tabs (Hide on scroll, proper margins, thin indicator)? I've tried SlidingTabs and some other libraries, but they all are outdated.

In more details, when I was developing for APIs 20 and less (before Android 5.0), I used to call `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` ?
Now with Android 5.0, the whole ActionBar is being replaced by ToolBar.

What is the right way to use Tabs in Material Design, using ToolBar? How can I make the Tabs hide on scroll?

Thanks!

Screenshots:

### [image: http://imgur.com/P1gjphx]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's layout for this. It doesn't look exactly like new play store, but pretty close. Just can't get rid of toolbar margin.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" />

            <widget.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/ViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Toolbar is hiding on scroll??

Comment: I found this layout only yields a slidingTabLayout that sits within the (normal) Toolbar space, between the left (menu/back) icon and any action items that may be set. Perhaps that is the case when there is enough room in the Toolbar? Subsequently, I moved to simply placing a SlidingTabLayout underneath the Toolbar, instead of within the Toolbar.

Comment: Check out one of the examples from Google: https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/activity_my_schedule_narrow.xml. Defining the title manually is typically not a good idea.

Comment: How do you add tabs to this tablayout?

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this from the new Android design library. Be sure to include compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```