# Material tabs with toolbar like design

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I saw this sample code for android playstore like layout on [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570322/android-5-0-material-tabs-with-toolbar), but due to low reputation i was not able to comment there. i am trying to achieve similar design for my project and would like if someone can help me get full code for this design apart from the layout file shared here.

Thanks.

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" />

            <widget.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/ViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add link of the post you are referring to

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570322/android-5-0-material-tabs-with-toolbar

Comment: Hi bro any success?  Or should I provide something for same

Comment: @kamalvaid The answer provided below worked for me but i would like to add drawer to it. So if you can help me with that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21/26543020#26543020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Take a look at this Library !

https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs**

Comment: ya i have seen that library and trying it out. thanks

Comment: okay this worked for me. but now i want to add a drawer in it so how can i do that? do you have any idea thanks.