# How to draw the material Sliding Tabs with navigation drawer and custom icon on toolbar?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, pagerslidingtabstrip

[image]

I want a layout exactly like this.I have searched a lot about this and tried the following links.

- [Android 5.0 material tabs with toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570322/android-5-0-material-tabs-with-toolbar)
- [Material tabs with toolbar like design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773372/material-tabs-with-toolbar-like-design?lq=1)

***This is my code I have tried so far.***

***MainActivity***

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NavigationView navigationView;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Toolbar mToolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        if (pager != null) {
            pager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        }

        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        if (tabs != null) {
            if (pager != null) {
                tabs.setViewPager(pager);
            }
        }



        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.home:

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        return true;

                    case R.id.about:


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "About Us Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.Share:


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Share Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    default:

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Somethings Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                }
            }
        });



        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            }
        };
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navigationView))
                {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView);
                }
                else
                {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(navigationView);
                }

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }





    public static class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{


        final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
        private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };

        public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // Generate title based on item position
            return tabTitles[position];
        }

        public static class PageFragment extends Fragment {
            private int mPage;
            public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

            public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
                PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
            }

            // Inflate the fragment layout we defined above for this fragment
// Set the associated text for the title
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, container, false);
                TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
                tvTitle.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
                return view;
            }


    }
}
}
```

***activity_main***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/overview_coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*With this code I am just getting navigation drawer without navigation Icon and no viewpager is implemented with this.*

Comment: try this tutorials.... http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial I think it will help you ..
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-design-style/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Comment: it do not tell how to add navigation drawer with it and search icon ??

Comment: Did you see section 7 ??